# Calling javascript function without onlick

Tags: javascript, html

how can i call javascript function without onclick

by just id, i want to only declare id inside button

i want to use it like

```
<button type="submit" id="bnt_b" id="myFunction">Try it</button>
```

instead

```
<button type="submit" id="bnt_b" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

like i want to avoid using onclick and call javascript by id

```
     <script>
     function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("bnt_b").disabled = true;
     
     var timeleft = 10;
     var progressTimer = setInterval(function() {
        if (timeleft <= 0) {
            clearInterval(progressTimer);
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = 'count ' + timeleft + ' time';
        }
        timeleft -= 1;
    }, 1000);
     setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById("bnt_b").disabled = false;
     }, 10000);
}
</script>

<button type="submit" id="bnt_b" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="progress"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("bnt_b").addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

Make sure the `script` tag this is in is below the `button` tag in the HTML or it won't be able to find the element.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for more information.

---

On a separate note, your function `myFunction` will be passed an event object, so you can reference the element like so:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  e.target.disabled = true;

  var timeleft = 10;
  var progressTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(progressTimer);
      document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = 'count ' + timeleft + ' time';
    }
    timeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function(){
    e.target.disabled = false;
  }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: how do you call this in html

Comment: https://gist.github.com/leonaves/3a563ed1a11854dcafca15b114616a46

Comment: Sorry, bad copy and paste, you don't need the onClick, I've updated the gist.

Comment: ok i saw it but is there way can make this without EventListener, just a standalone function run by when i click button like a function to call it by id

Comment: because i tried this earlier the EventListener with click but it peforms same as the onClick, i wanted to make it something standalone working by id when i call it on button or when i press button

Comment: No, you can't invoke javascript from user action without an event listener. The two ways to do that are by using `onclick` or by using `addEventListener`.

Comment: its possible 100% see this sample code [link]( https://codeshare.io/5QpVnq)

Comment: I don't understand, the code you have sent doesn't call any javascript when the button is pressed? (https://codepen.io/leonaves/pen/BajrKaV)

Comment: what i mean the way that code works, its same my question how i wanted it to work. no event listener  and onlick. it works by id inside button

Comment: The code you have sent doesn't do anything when the button is clicked. If you want to do something when the button is clicked you need an event listener.